# How to make turtle draw quicker?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

My code:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
bob = turtle.Turtle()
screen.bgcolor("black")
bob.speed(0)


def crazy():
    for i in range(360):
        for colors in ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'blue']:
            bob.pencolor(colors)
            bob.forward(i)
            bob.left(124)


crazy()
```

I want to speed this process of drawing up by a lot so it draws the final image quicker. Any ideas on how to do it?

Btw I'm working on an art montage python project and you can probably guess this one is going to be in it. All help is appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using  `turtle.tracer(0, 0)` which will stop refreshing every time and at the end do `turtle.update()`

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
bob = turtle.Turtle()
screen.bgcolor("black")

bob.speed(0)

turtle.tracer(0, 0)


def crazy():
    for i in range(360):
        for colors in ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'blue']:
            bob.pencolor(colors)
            bob.forward(i)
            bob.left(124)


crazy()
turtle.update()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It is, admittedly faster by a lot, and I'm fine with this level, but I'm curious. Any way on making it faster?

Comment: @kidwhowantstolearnpython PyQt5 can do it an order of magnitude faster